# Measuring page elements and making images take the remaining vertical space

Tags: tex-core

In a document comprising an image, then a section header, then another image:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[height=???]{foo.png}

\section{Boo}

\includegraphics[height=???]{foo.png}

\end{document}
```

How to compute image heights such that they're
equally high, and together take the vertical space that the section header
doesn't occupy?

[image]

Assigning the section header to a box adds or removes vertical space in ways I
don't understand, and measuring the box height is therefore not accurate:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

\setbox0=\vbox{\section{Boo}}

\includegraphics[height=\dimexpr(\textheight-\ht0)/2\relax]{foo.png}

\box0

\includegraphics[height=\dimexpr(\textheight-\ht0)/2\relax]{foo.png}
\end{document}
```

Since `\vfill` knows how to fill space, is there a analogous way for
an image to do so too? I know we can't measure a `\vfill`, but could
there be another way to measure the free height between two elements?